# sql count how many duplicated values

Tags: sql

lets say i have a query like this

```
select 
    
    dso.employee_id,
    e.nip as nik,
    e.name_related,
    dso.partner_id,
    sum(dsol.product_qty) as repeat_order

    
from dealer_sale_order dso
left join dealer_sale_order_line dsol on dsol.dealer_sale_order_line_id = dso.id
left join hr_employee e on e.id = dso.employee_id
left join dym_branch b on b.id = dso.branch_id

group by nik, name_related, dso.partner_id,dso.employee_id
having sum(dsol.product_qty) > 1
```

and it return values like this :

```
employee_id      nik            name_related         partner_id      repeat_order
29064            14070015       TRI                  5108966         2
29064            14070015       TRI                  5648397         3
29067            16070023       WIWI                 5909391         2
29067            16070023       WIWI                 5896655         3
29066            17040022       MURNI                5922380         2
32913            MT-16110024    LUCKY                5774998         2
```

after got that table, i want to return table like this:

```
employee_id      nik            name_related        count
29064            14070015       TRI                 2
29067            16070023       WIWI                2
29066            17040022       MURNI               1
32913            MT-16110024    LUCKY               1
```

the question is how do i make table like that with sql query?

i tried this but it doesnt work

```
select
   ro.employee_id,
   ro.nik,
   ro.name_related,
   count(ro.*) as count
left join (
  # query above
)ro on ro.employee_id = dso.employee_id

group by employee_id, nik, name_related
```

Comment: In your query attempt (to get the distinct values/count), you have a left join, with the join predicate being "ro.employee_id = dso.employee_id".  Where does the "dso" alias exist in that query, to be joined with the sub-query?  Think about that - it doesn't make any sense, huh?  In fact, your initial query (that gets all the rows of repeat orders) could just be a CTE (common table expression), from which you can then get the distinct output that you're after.  Are you familiar with CTEs?

Comment: *i tried this but it doesnt work* Replace `left join` with `FROM` and remove `on` clause at all.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want to implement.